# Change readonly attribute of input element: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add or remove an attribute from an html input element.

What i'm done is this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputState: 'readOnly'};
}
```

And the render function:

```
<input className="form-control" type="text" value={floor} {...this.state.inputState} />
```

As you can see i want set the "readOnly" attribute on the input element.
But now i get an error which says:

> Unknown props `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` on  tag. Remove these props from the element

When an user is clicking on the input element it should become editable, so i want to dynamicly change this attribute.

But how can i do that?

Comment: If you really want to spread the state. Simply do: `<input className="form-control" type="text" value={floor} {...this.state} />`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To control the mode of `input` element define `readOnly` attribute with it and control it's value by state variable, Whenever you update the state value react will re-render the component and it will change the mode on the basis of state value.

Check this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {readOnly: true}
    this._click = this._click.bind(this);
  }

  _click(){
     this.setState(prevState => ({readOnly: !prevState.readOnly}))
  }
  
  render(){
     return <div>
        <input readOnly={this.state.readOnly}/>
        <button onClick={this._click}>Toggle</button>
     </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`this.state = { inputState: { readOnly: true }};`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {readOnly: true};
}

render() {
    return (<input className="form-control" type="text" value={floor} readOnly={this.state.readOnly} />)
}
```